# show data name which one project with user use laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, pivot-table

I want to display User Name who have one project with user logged in. use relation table user_id and project_id in UserProject as table pivot.

**my index controller**

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::with('projects')->get();
    return view ('teams.index', compact('users', 'project'));
}
```

**my index view**

```
<table class="table table-consended">
  <tr>
    <th> <h4>No</h4> </th>
    <th> <h4>Name</h4> </th>
    <th> <h4>Role</h4> </th>
    <th> <h4>Project</h4> </th>
    </tr>
          @foreach($users as $item => $user)                        
     <tr>
        <td>{{$item+1}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
        <td>{{$user->role->name}}</td>
        <td>
            @foreach ($user->projects as $project)
             {{$project->project_name}}
            @endforeach
        </td>
     </tr>
       @endforeach()
  </table>
```

when I try this, the User Name are display in index, although its not in the same project.
[image: index blade]

Comment: are you getting any problem

Comment: all user are displays

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is get the current `user` then:

```
$request->user(); //or Auth::user();

//if you using guard

$request->user('guard-name');

//or

Auth::guard('guard-name')->user();
```

You can use this like:

```
public function index()
{
    $user = User::with('projects')->find(request()->user()->id);
    return view ('teams.index', compact('user'));
}
```

Comment: where I put this `$request->user(); //or Auth::user();` ?

Comment: where to put this code `$request->user(); //or Auth::user();
//if you using guard
$request->user('guard-name'); //or Auth::guard('guard-name')->user();`

Comment: why use `$request`. this in index

Comment: i already gave many options.. if dont want use it, just use other option..

Comment: where I put this `$request->user(); //or Auth::user();` ? in User Models or Project Models.?

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
public function index()
{
    $users = User::where('id',Auth::user()->id)->with('projects')->get();
    return view ('teams.index', compact('users', 'project'));
}
```

in your user model call relation

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany(ProjectModel::class, 'user_id')->with('user');
}
```

in your projects model call relation

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(UserModel::class,'id');
}
```

Comment: it works, but it just display user and his project, not display other user who has one project with auth user.

Comment: then you have to call a relation within the project model

Comment: this code `public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_projects');
    }` ??
this in my model project

Comment: but it just display user and his project, not display other user who has same project with auth user

Comment: you have to access it like `@foreach ($user->projects as $project)` and `foreach($project->user as $user_data)`

Comment: like this .? `<tr>
                            <td>{{$item+1}}</td>
                            <td>{{$user->name}}</td>
                            <td>{{$user->role->name}}</td>
                            <td>
                                @foreach ($user->projects as $project)
                                    foreach($project->user as $user_data)
                                    {{$project->project_name}}
                                @endforeach
                            </td>
                        </tr>`

Comment: use this `<tr> <td>{{$item+1}}</td> <td>{{$user->name}}</td> <td>{{$user->role->name}}</td> <td> @foreach ($user->projects as $project) foreach($project->user as $user_data) {{$user_data->name}} @endforeach </td> </tr>`

Comment: What erroe you are gtting

Comment: add @ sign befor foreach and also add @endforeach

Comment: `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Comment: add `{{dd($project)}} ` after you second foreach loop and share the screen shot

Comment: in my controller i just use this `$users = User::where('id', Auth::user()->id)->with('projects')->get();
        // dd($users);
        return view ('teams.index', compact('users'));`

Comment: thats ok and have you call `with('user')` in your projects function

Comment: if I change `with('projects')` to `with('user')` any error `Call to undefined relationship [user] on model [App\User]`